# How to get correct replacement of ISO-8859-1 characters to UTF-8?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to replace ISO-8859-1 characters from file below to be valid for UTF-8 encoding.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<A NAME="top"></A>

<TABLE border=0 width=609 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<TR><td rowspan=2><img src="http://www.example.com" width=10></td>
<TD width=609 valign=top>

<p>'</p>
<p>*</p>
<p>-</p>
<p>—</p>
<p>§</p>
<p>«</p>
<p>»</p>
<p>¿</p>
<p>Á</p>

</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

</body>
</html>
```

Doing some research I found that the issue is related with `locale` language and I was able to build this awk program, but only replaces the first 2 characters (`'` and `*`)

```
LC_ALL=ISO_8859-1 awk '{
   gsub(/charset=iso-8859-1/, "charset=UTF-8"  ,  $0)
   gsub(/\047/, "\\&apos;"  ,  $0)
   gsub(/*/, "\\&ast;"      ,  $0)
   gsub(/–/, "\\&ndash;"    ,  $0)
   gsub(/—/, "\\&mdash;"    ,  $0)
   gsub(/§/, "\\&sect;"     ,  $0)
   gsub(/«/, "\\&laquo;"    ,  $0)
   gsub(/»/, "\\&raquo;"    ,  $0)
   gsub(/¿/, "\\&iquest;"   ,  $0)
   gsub(/Á/, "\\&Aacute;"   ,  $0)
   print
   }' t.html | iconv -f ISO_8859-1 -t UTF-8
```

This is the current output (showing below partial output, only lines affected by the program):

```
<p>&apos;</p>
<p>&ast;</p>
<p>-</p>
<p>-</p>
<p>§</p>
<p>«</p>
<p>»</p>
<p>¿</p>
<p>Á</p>
```

and expected output is:

```
<p>&ast;</p>
<p>&ndash;</p>
<p>&mdash;</p>
<p>&sect;</p>
<p>&laquo;</p>
<p>&raquo;</p>
<p>&iquest;</p>
<p>&Aacute;</p>
```

I've already tried a similar code using `sed` but the same issue.

How to fix this?

Below locale config:

```
***Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Your awk command works fine here with gawk except `ndash`, I guess it's plain dash (`-`) in your HTML file

Comment: Do you get the expected output? I mean, all HTML entities instead of symbols?

Comment: Yes, I do except `&ndash;`. I'm using gawk 5.0.1

Comment: You're welcome. If you figure out the problem please share it here, I really wonder what's wrong

Comment: Can you run `perl -ne 'print $1 if (m[<p>(.*)</p>])' t.html | base64`, and paste result ?

Comment: @oguz ismail base64 allows others (like you and me) to get to the data much more easily.

Comment: Try adding `-v BINMODE=3` to the gawk arg list (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables).

Comment: My guess is that you saved your awk program in a file encoded in UTF-8. In this case, the literals such as `§` in `gsub` are interpreted by awk as sequences of characters, which cannot match as expected against input files using single-byte encodings. You can either save your awk script in ISO-8859-1, or keep it in UTF-8 but replace the literal characters by their ISO-8859-1 codes, e.g. `/\xA7/` instead of `/§/`. Also note that mdash and ndash are not part of ISO-8859-1 so it's useless to add these cases. If you do see them in a document then it means that it's actually not using ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Phillipe what does that perl command do? Converts to base64 only the HTML paragraphs?

Comment: @EdMorton I tried adding your suggestion and the same result. I forgot to that I running Ubuntu on Windows 10 if that matters.

Comment: @luciole75w I actually paste the awk code directly on terminal. I don't have saved as awk program. I'm running Ubuntu on Windows 10. I'll try your suggestions

Comment: @Ger Cas the perl command extracts the 9 characters in your post, so that we can see how they are encoded.

Comment: @Philippe This is the perl command print `JyotLaeru7/BycvN0dPa4ejp7e7x8/T6/A==`

Comment: @luciole75w Your suggestion has worked. You should write it as answer. I mean this suggestion `replace the literal characters by their ISO-8859-1 codes, e.g. /\xA7/ instead of /§`

Comment: Glad it helped. I just made it clean in an answer, please let me know if anything is unclear. Btw I said earlier that it was useless to deal with mdash/ndash (which would be true for ISO-8859-1 strictly speaking) but actually I just noticed that you are probably using Windows-1252 instead, so these two characters may be useful eventually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is likely due to an encoding mismatch between the input file and the awk script.

Please first note that there is probably a (very common) confusion between ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252 here. The html sample in the original post contains em/en dash characters which are not part of the [ISO-8859-1 layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout), so it certainly uses another encoding, probably [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set) (which is a superset of ISO-8859-1 including the dash characters) since the OP reported to use Ubuntu through the Windows subsystem layer.

I'll then assume that the html input file is indeed encoded with Windows-1252. So non-ASCII characters (code points ≥ 128) use only one byte.

If the awk program is loaded from a file encoded in UTF-8, or even directly typed in a terminal window which uses the UTF-8 endoding, then the regular expressions and literal strings embedded in the program are also encoded in UTF-8. So non-ASCII characters use multiple bytes.

For example, the character `§` (code point 167 = 0xA7), is represented by the byte `A7` in Windows-1252 and the sequence of bytes `C2 A7` in UTF-8. If you use `gsub(/§/, "S")` in your UTF-8 encoded awk program, then awk looks for the sequence `C2 A7` in the input file which only contains `A7`. It will not match. Unless you are (un)lucky enough to have a character `Â` (code point 194 = 0xC2) hanging out just before your `§`.

Changing the locale does not help here because it only tells awk how to parse its input (data and program), whereas what you need here is to transcode either the data or the regular expressions. For this to work you would have to be able to specify the locale of the data independently of the locale of the program, which is not supported.

So, assuming that your system is set up with an UTF-8 locale and that your awk script uses this locale (no matter if loaded from a file or typed in a terminal), here are several methods you can use to align the input file and the regular expressions on the same encoding so that `gsub` works as expected.

Please note that these suggestions stick to your first awk command since it is the source of the issue. The final pipe to `iconv` is needed only if you intentionally does not transform all the special characters you may have in the input to html entities. Otherwise the output of awk is plain ASCII so already UTF-8 compliant.

#### Option 1 : convert the input file from Windows-1252 to UTF-8

No need for another `iconv` step after that in any case.

```
iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 t.html | awk '{
   gsub(/charset=iso-8859-1/, "charset=UTF-8")
   gsub(/\047/, "\\&apos;")
   gsub(/\*/, "\\&ast;")
   gsub(/–/, "\\&ndash;")
   gsub(/—/, "\\&mdash;")
   gsub(/§/, "\\&sect;")
   gsub(/«/, "\\&laquo;")
   gsub(/»/, "\\&raquo;")
   gsub(/¿/, "\\&iquest;")
   gsub(/Á/, "\\&Aacute;")
   print
   }'
```

#### Option 2 : convert the awk program from UTF-8 to Windows-1252

Because the awk program may want to have fun too. Let's use process substitution.

```
awk -f <(iconv -t WINDOWS-1252 <<'EOS'
{
   gsub(/charset=iso-8859-1/, "charset=UTF-8")
   gsub(/'/, "\\&apos;")
   gsub(/\*/, "\\&ast;")
   gsub(/–/, "\\&ndash;")
   gsub(/—/, "\\&mdash;")
   gsub(/§/, "\\&sect;")
   gsub(/«/, "\\&laquo;")
   gsub(/»/, "\\&raquo;")
   gsub(/¿/, "\\&iquest;")
   gsub(/Á/, "\\&Aacute;")
   print
}
EOS
) t.html
```

#### Option 3 : save the awk/schell script in a file encoded in Windows-1252

... with your favorite tool.

#### Option 4 : switch the encoding of your terminal session to Windows-1252

In case you type/paste the awk command in a terminal of course.

Note that this different from setting the locale (LC_CTYPE). I'm not aware of a way to do this programmatically. If somebody knows, feel free to contribute.

#### Option 5 : avoid non-ASCII characters altogether in the awk program

Sounds anyway a good practice in my opinion.

```
awk '{
   gsub(/charset=iso-8859-1/, "charset=UTF-8")
   gsub(/\047/, "\\&apos;")
   gsub(/\*/, "\\&ast;")
   gsub(/\226/, "\\&ndash;")
   gsub(/\227/, "\\&mdash;")
   gsub(/\247/, "\\&sect;")
   gsub(/\253/, "\\&laquo;")
   gsub(/\273/, "\\&raquo;")
   gsub(/\277/, "\\&iquest;")
   gsub(/\301/, "\\&Aacute;")
   print
   }' t.html
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for your extra detailed answer and for share so many options about this.

Comment: I have just seen your other question looking for a more flexible approach, it's a good idea in my opinion. Even if awk was indeed not the best tool to handle html entities, the details and methods given here are still generic enough to eventually help in other circumstances so it was worth making an answer anyway.

Comment: Hi, yes. I tested your solution and it works, but after that I see that the HTML file had "mixed" characters. Sometimes the character itself and sometimes the hex value and in that way the replacement done by awk program needed to be repeated having the correct pattern to search for the hex representation. But your solution helped me to understand better about encoding and will be useful for others in the future. Thanks for take time to help!